# I cant get the right result with if statement in excel using both IF with AND statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to retrieve DIV 1, DIV 2, DIV 3 AND DIV 4 if the values meet the conditions of AND but it only returns DIV 3 even if the values don't meet the condition.

The If statement have created is as below

```
=IF(AND(O2<=6,V2<=6),"DIV 1",
 IF(AND(O2>=7,V2<=6),"DIV 2",
 IF(AND(O2>=7,V2>=7),"DIV 3",
 IF(AND(O2=9,V2=9),"DIV 4"))))
```

I want to get DIV 1 if cells O2 and V2 are less than or equal to 6,
I want to get DIV 2 if cells O2 is greater or equal to 7 and V2 is less than or equal to 6,
I want to get DIV 3 if cells O2 and V2 are greater or equal to 7,
I want to get DIV 4 if cells O2  and  V2 are  equal to 9.

Comment: Will never get to DIV 4 as 9 is greater than 7. Suggest you check your logic test order.

Comment: Do you want DIV 2 if both are equal to 9? or DIV 4? Function says DIV 4, but question text says DIV 2.

Comment: i want DIV 4 if both are equal to 9

Comment: Then you need to edit the question: " i want to get DIV 2 if cells O2 and V2 are equal to 9".

Comment: have done so , please do you have any way forward

Answer (score 1):

Try this, change the test order as I suggested:

```
=IF(AND(O2>=9,V2>=9),"DIV 4",IF( AND(O2>=7,V2>=7),"DIV 3",IF(AND(O2>=7,V2<=6),"DIV 2",IF(AND(O2<=6,V2<=6),"DIV 1"))))
```

Tested and works:
[image]

Comment: it only produces DIV 4 even if the values are of DIV 1

Comment: the values am trying to compare in O2 AND V2 are created by a function this =IF(M2="","",IF(M2="D1","1",IF(M2="D2","2",IF(M2="C3","3",IF(M2="C4","4",IF(M2="C5","5",IF(M2="C6","6",IF(M2="P7","7",IF(M2="P8","8",IF(M2>="F9","9"))))))))))

Comment: "IF(M2="D1","1"," is D1 referring to a cell? Or is cell M2 compared to D1 as a character and a number? If D1 is a cell then it should not be in quotes. idem the others. Also have you copy / pasted values to see exactly what results you get? you may not be testing what you expect. Aslo, if you put "1" and "2" then those are not numbers they are then text and don't always behave the same, so if you want the results to be numerical then do this: IF(M2="D1",1, instead.

Comment: D1 is not a cell, its just a String compare with cell M2

Comment: Then check what else I suggested. Also what is in cell M2?

Comment: @IntelPower then please vote for it or accept it. Cheers, glad it is working.